# How to deserialize a serialized queryset in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-serializer, django-sessions

**views.py**

```
def ipd_report_view(request):
    report=IpdReport.objects.all()
    myFilter=IpdFilters(request.POST, queryset=report)
    report=myFilter.qs
    total1=report.aggregate(Sum('realization__amount_received'))
    total2=report.aggregate(Sum('realization__deficit_or_surplus_amount'))
    rp=serializers.serialize('json', report)
    request.session['report']=rp
    context={'report': report, 'total1':total1, 'total2':total2, 'myFilter':myFilter}
    return render(request, 'account/ipdreport.html', context)
```

In another `view` function, I have to use the data in the `session` to be able to make the function export the data to an excel file.

I did `rp=request.session['report']`, but this `object` is a `string` object, so how do I go about converting this back to a `queryset`? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question specifically asks about getting a `QuerySet` back so it's worth noting that calling `serializers.deserialize` (per @cabesuon's answer) will not do that - it returns a generator yielding `DeserializedObject`. If that's not good enough for your use-case you may want to reconstruct a `QuerySet`:

```py
IpdReport.objects.filter(
    pk__in=map(
        lambda o: o.object.pk,
        serializers.deserialize("json", request.session["report"]),
    )
)
```

Edit: to elaborate a bit more on what's happening here:

[Django documentation about serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data) notes:

> The Django object itself can be inspected as `deserialized_object.object`.

Further, the `pk` property of that Django object [is provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut) as a convenient way of making use of the primary key.

Essentially what we're doing with the functional programming `map()` construct is turning our returned generator of `DeseralizedObject` instances into a sequence of just primary keys. The lambda's entire purpose is to access our desired properties (it's equivalent to `operator.itemgetter("object.pk")` but doesn't require importing the `operator` module and is more immediately obvious). After that, we pass that resulting sequence to `.filter()` to do a lookup of `IpdReport` instances that ended up in the `QuerySet` that you serialized.

If you want to read more about functional programing in python you may want to check out the [HOWTO on the topic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html).

It's also worth noting that this entire approach has a potentially significant downside - the state of the database may be altered between serialization and deserialization - this can cause some inconsistencies (getting results that no longer match previously applied filters or, inversely - not getting results that should match the filters but previously didn't). For that reason you may want to look into [serializing `QuerySet.query`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#pickling-querysets).

Comment: Thanks. It works! I am a beginner and this was something new for me to learn. Thanks a lot for that. I just have one doubt. Would you be more generous and explain a little about that expression in the lambda function, "o.object.pk". Where can I learn more about this expression? And thanks for your answer once again. :)

Comment: @noob87 Added an edit that should hopefully provide more context and point to some additional resources. Do let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll surely look into it and try and learn better. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the reverse method, `deserialize`,

[Django Docs - Serialization, deserializing-data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data)

In your case, it would be something like this,

```
// serializers.deserialize returns an iterator,
// but we know is just one element
obj = list(serializers.deserialize("json", request.session['report']))[0]
// obj is a DeserializedObject not the instance of the model
// to inspect the element just use the object property
rp = IpdReport.objects.get(pk=obj.object.pk)
```

Comment: Like, rp=request.session['report'], then, rp_qs=serializers.deserialize("queryset", rp)? What do I put in place of the first argument?

Comment: I just edit the answer to include an example on a possible way to achieve what you want